# MVC SlidingExpiration and Validating Post Requets

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, post, forms-authentication

I'm working on a site which uses FormAuthentication.SlidingExpiration.
My understanding is that this works by using a FormsAuthentication Action to intercept the first call after being half way through the expiration period to set a new expiration time.

If this first request is a GET then there are no issues.

If the first request is a POST of a Form which contains html in a field then FormAuthentication action itself errors as it thinks a dangerous request is being made.  This occurs before it gets to the intended Action which is decorated to allow html for specific variables.

Has anyone encountered this before? Or have any thoughts on how to retain the use of SlidingExpiration and still be able to Post html values?

Answer (score 0):

To share the knowledge that we learnt whilst resolving this issue:
Essentially the MVC framework contains two copies of Forms Authentication, one which performs validation and one which doesn't.  Both are still present in the framework so that the MVC code can continue to function when it natively encounters issues like the above.
To resolve the issue we needed to make sure that we are using this second version:

< httpRuntime ... targetFramework="4.7.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" />